# My java server does not recognize the HTTP session. Client on VB.NET

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, httpsession

I have a java application running like a server in Tomcat for my web app and my app cordova (same as the web application but with functions like a BarCode Scanner).
With this application the server works perfectly. But now I am developing a little part of the aplication in VB.NET with compact framework 3.5 and when I log in the server store my session variable... 
Ok, that's fine but if I make a new request, my server detects a new session and for this my session variable is not here and for each request is opening a new Http Session. 
I think the problem is in VB. That's my code where I open requests to my server

```
 Try
            Dim url = "http://192.168.2.166:8084/SCTraker_Servidor/api/Session"
            Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

            Dim dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            dataStream.Close()

            Dim httpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
            httpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

            If httpWebResponse.StatusCode = 200 Then
                Me.Hide()
                httpWebRequest.Abort()
                httpWebResponse.Close()
                Home.Show()
            Else
                BarraEstado.Text = "No ha rellenado el campo usuario o contraseña"
            End If

        Catch webException As WebException
            BarraEstado.Text = webException.Message
            Dim respuesta = webException.Response

        Catch socketException As Sockets.SocketException
            BarraEstado.Text = socketException.Message

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Tomcat you have to use either the appended `JSESSIONID` parameter from the previous request or use the cookie `JSESSIONID` sent by the server.

When receiving the response from the Tomcat server look for a cookie named `JSESSIONID` and save it. In the next request set this coockie again.

If the server does not send a coockie then look for a `String` that starts with `;JSESSIONID=...`appended to the URL after authenticated. Append this String to every request you make to the Tomcat server.